# Am i forced to use nested tables for layout to scale a textarea?(example html included)

Tags: html, css, css-float, html-table

The website i am building has the requirement of increasing the size of a textarea as the resolution goes up.
 I tried doing this with floating and non floating divs but in every scenario i tried so far the divs aligned nicely but i had no way of controlling the textarea size. 

Standard tables do however provide this functionality out of the box except for 1 ie compatibility problem.

The following code works as intended in firefox and ie(quircks mode)
 standard ie fails to resize the textarea height.
I don't mind some out of the box thinking, it don't have to be tables divs or whatever as long as it gets the job done.

I am aware javascript can do some resolution calculations but that solution feels a bit too complicated for a simple layout issue. The simpler & lesser code the better imo.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<table style="width: 100%">
<tr>
    <td style="width: 300px">
        <table class="clsDataGrid" width="100%" height="350px">
            <tr style="height:350px;background-color:blue;">
                <td style="height:350px">test</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br/>      
        <table width="100%">
           <tr>
                <td style="background-color:red;height:100px">test</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>

    <td style="padding-left : 1em;height: 100%">
        <table class="clsDataGrid" style="width: 100%;height: 100%">
            <tr>
                <th>Description</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="height: 100%">
                    <textarea style="resize: none; width:99%;height: 100%">DATAAAAA</textarea>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td> 
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you specify a width in percents, the text area should scale with its parent. But I think it is better to give it a width of 100% instead of 99% and control the spacing around it by setting a margin on its parent.

Comment: You have a good point and i'll be sure to do that. It doesn't however fix my main issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so solution 3 - using no js - you have to go tables.
Watch out for how I had to force the description label in - its a bug fix not me being an idiot.

```
<!--Solution 3-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    body {padding:0; margin:0;}
    table td {vertical-align: top;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table width="100%" height="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td style="height:350px; background-color:blue; color:white; padding:0 24px;">
            Blue Test
        </td>
        <td rowspan="2" style="padding:31px 24px 0; position:relative; height:100%">
                <label style="position:absolute; top:0; left:24px;">Description</label>
                <textarea style="resize: none; width:100%; height:100%;">DATAAAAA</textarea>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="height:100px; background-color:red; color:white; padding:0 24px;">
            Red Test
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

---

As with anything like this there are a bunch of solutions - here are two off the top of my head - a place for you to start - I haven't test cross browser.

Hope they help.

```
<!--Solution 1-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div style="display:table; width:100%">
    <div style="display:table-cell; width:30%;">
        <div style="height:350px; background-color:blue; color:white; padding:0 24px;">
            Blue Test
        </div>
        <div style="height:100px; background-color:red; color:white; padding:0 24px;">
            Red Test
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle">
        <div style="padding:0 24px;">
            <span>Description</span>
            <textarea style="resize: none; width:100%;height: 100%">DATAAAAA</textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>

<!--Solution 2-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div style="width:100%">
    <div style="display:inline-block; width:30%;">
        <div style="height:350px; background-color:blue;">
            Blue Test
        </div>
        <div style="height:100px; background-color:red;">
            Red Test
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="display:inline-block; width:69%">
        <span>Description</span>
        <textarea style="resize: none; width:99%;height: 100%">DATAAAAA</textarea>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I love how you fixed my horizontal sizing issue with divs. For that i thank you. But the height problem still seems an issue in both ie and firefox. I would like the text area + Description to be the same height as the left side. I tried adding some heights 100% to both your solutions but it seems i am lacking some fundamental knowledge in this area because it won't budge a pixel.

Comment: so when you say same as left side can you clarify - you want the text area to take up 100% height of red and blue block and also take up  100% of the remaining width?

Comment: The text area + the description span should be 100% height of the blue and red div.

Comment: Your solution nr 3 does exactly what i want it to. I think we followed similar paths because i had trouble with the description span as well, i can see how your bugfix fixes my issue with using 1 giant table. it's ashame it can't be done with divs(and a bit surprising for me) but your answer fits my need, thank you !